# Mantis Bugtracker change id

Tags: php, mysql, mantis

I have 3 projects and I wanted to change the default ‚id‘.

Example: Project 1: „devBranch“
ID: devBranch-000001
devBranch-000002
...
Project 2: „stable“:
stable-000001
stable-000002

Same for the other projects.

Right now Mantis just auto inc. the id